Excel VBA code use value of a cell as the row number position for cell values
I have an Excel spreadsheet with exported sales information. I want to summarize the information onto another tab. Basically Summary Sheet column A will list a Customers name, then the items they purchased. Then the next Customer and the items they purchased, in the same column.
I was able to figure out how to extract all the customer names and how often they showed up. But I can't figure out how to copy their names, while leaving space for their items to be listed under their name.
I have step 1 figure out, but need help with step 2

I was thinking of using a function that would let me loop through the list and use the values in column B as the row position when pasting the Customer Names.
Something like
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim NumRows As Long

NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Cells(1,4).Value = Cells(1,1).Value

j="B1"

For i=2 To NumRows

    Cells([j+3],4).Value = Cells("A[i]",1).Value

    j=j+"B[i]"+2

Next i


    Dim CustomerRange As Range ' CustomerName-StartPosition
    Dim GoalRange As Range     ' Range, where it is Printed
    Dim NumRows As Long        ' Number of Customers
    Dim i As Long              ' For CustomerNames
    Dim j As Long              ' For CustomerAmount
    Dim k As Long              ' For Whole offset of GoalRange

    Set CustomerRange = Range("A1")
    Set GoalRange = Range("D1")
    NumRows = Range(CustomerRange, CustomerRange.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    CustomerRange.Offset(NumRows, 1).Value = CustomerRange.Value ' Dont know why you want this but here it is

    For i = 0 To NumRows - 1
        GoalRange.Offset(i + k, 0).Value = CustomerRange.Offset(i, 0).Value
        k = k + 1
        For j = 1 To CustomerRange.Offset(i, 1).Value
            GoalRange.Offset(i + k, 0).Value = CustomerRange.Offset(i, 0).Value & " Item " & j
            k = k + 1
        Next
    Next

